# why it need to double click first time to load jquery?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

when i try to open popup on button click it is not open on first click.
i use J Query with Angular js for open right side popup on button click but i got problem for open it . on button click event i wrote this code .

when i click on this button `<a type="button" class="btn border-button cd-btn" ng-click="Bookservice(item)">Book</a>`

```
$scope.Bookservice=function(item)
{
     $('.cd-btn').on('click', function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
       $('.cd-panel').addClass('is-visible');
     });
     //clode the lateral panel
     $('.cd-panel').on('click', function(event){
     if( $(event.target).is('.cd-panel') || $(event.target).is('.cd-panel-close') ) { 
        $('.cd-panel').removeClass('is-visible');
        event.preventDefault();
      }
   });
}
```

and popup code something like this

```
<div class="cd-panel from-right">
    <a href="#0" class="cd-panel-close">Close</a>
    <div class="cd-panel-container">
        <div class="cd-panel-content">
```

from this code i try to open popup when i click on button at that time it use previous code which i wrote , but it is not open on first click when i click second time on button at that time open popup. so , i want that my popup must be open on first click after page load .

Thanks

Comment: why you put to $(".cd-panel") click?

Comment: i don't know anything about it i just copy past this code .

Comment: ya it is class of my dialog box

Comment: can you provide fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attaching click event when `Bookservice(item)` is called.

Put `$('.cd-panel').addClass('is-visible');` this in Bookservice function.

```
$scope.Bookservice=function(item)
{
     $('.cd-panel').addClass('is-visible');
     //clode the lateral panel
     $('.cd-panel').on('click', function(event){
     if( $(event.target).is('.cd-panel') || $(event.target).is('.cd-panel-close') ) { 
        $('.cd-panel').removeClass('is-visible');
        event.preventDefault();
      }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.Bookservice=function(item)
{
     $('.cd-btn').on('click', function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
       if(!$(this).hasClass("is-visible"))
         $('.cd-panel').addClass('is-visible');
       else
         $('.cd-panel').removeClass('is-visible');
     });
     //clode the lateral panel

   }
```

and use ng-click in your view

Comment: no this can't work for me , it need all time double click and in my code it need only one time double click after load page .

Answer (score 0):

logic related to DOM manipulation should not be written in $scope function of controller, i think you are doing so, please create directive to show pop-up and implement logic for DOM manipulation there, This link [Open custom Pop up in Angular](http://jsbin.com/jehaxatoye/1/edit?html,css,js,output) has proper implementation approach for your problem